# Google App Engine: getting "Max number of files and blobs is 10000." when deploying app with only 1000 files

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am getting `Max number of files and blobs is 10000.` error when trying to deploy my application (it only contains 1000 files max) into Google App Engine.

Is there a typical bug that I am hitting here? My first guess was maybe that the fact that the mimetype error maybe throwing into a cyclical cloning of my files, but it is hard to say.

**Appengine trackback...**

```
03:44 PM Host: appengine.google.com
03:44 PM Application: fakeid (was: None); version: fakeversion (was: None)
03:44 PM Starting update of app: fakeid, version: fakeversion
03:44 PM Getting current resource limits.
03:44 PM Scanning files on local disk.
03:44 PM Scanned 14500 files.
Could not guess mimetype for datatools/pensieve/static/js/src/library/agGrid/CONTRIBUTING.md.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for datatools/pensieve/static/js/src/library/agGrid/README.md.  Using application/octet-stream.
03:45 PM Cloning 649 static files.
03:45 PM Cloning 14623 application files.
03:45 PM Cloned 10000 files.
03:45 PM Rolling back the update.
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
Max number of files and blobs is 10000.
--- end server output ---
```

Comment: It said scanned 14500 files, I doubt you have 1000 files max

Comment: Add `--verbose` to your deployment command to see the actual files being considered. You may want to redirect the output to a file, though...

Comment: I once accidentally added a symbolic link that caused the uploader to loop and recursively upload files until some limit was reached.  You might have done the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `git` the number of 'files' in your project can explode. Add the following to your `app.yaml`

```
skip_files:
- .git
```

Make sure if you start to explicitly define the skip_files list, you also add in the old defaults outlined here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files